# Input languages switch spontaneously too fast

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am using both Arabic and English as input languages and set the switching key combination to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. Sometimes i find the languages keep switching spontaneously too fast that I type a letter in Arabic and another in English. No key combination work at this case and the keyboard indicator in the top panel becomes unresponsive. The only solution is to restart.

I used 10.10 for a month or two and had no problem until one day I updated my system but the kernel seems not compatible with my Laptop and I couldn't neither boot nor fix ubuntu so I had to reinstall. The problem started to appear then. I thought it might be my CD has some scratches and missing files I tried to reburn the image several times and even downloading an entirely new image but nothing works I get the same problem.

On windows everything is working fine that's why I am excluding a keyboard problem as I use the same key combination as windows.

NB: I can remove Arabic and this solves the problem but not usable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug and it needs to be reported and fixed for future releases, see here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs